# find matched rows in two matrix by python

Tags: python, matrix

I have two matrixes. one(matrix a) has 1681 rows and the other one(matrix b) has 10-30 rows. I want a fast method to find out which rows in the matrix a will be matched in matrix b. I have tried np.where() so far. but I need to use for loop and check the rows in matrix b line by line. I was wondering if there is the more efficient method for this problem.

Comment: If you could add some example inputs together with the corresponding output (using small matrices, obviously), it would probably make the question rather easier to understand.

Comment: Check out [ask] for some tips on asking questions. Show us a sample of your input, explain specifically what you want to achieve and then show us your expected output.

Comment: for i in range(pp1):
                  result1 = np.where((Pixel_material.X1 <= data_ANT_to_pixel[i][0]) & (Pixel_material.X2 > data_ANT_to_pixel[i][0]) & (Pixel_material.Y1 <= data_ANT_to_pixel[i][1]) & (Pixel_material.Y2 > data_ANT_to_pixel[i][1]))
So, here is the for loop. data_ANT_to_pixel is the matrix that I wanna find its value line by line in the Pixel_material ( Pixel_material = pd.DataFrame() ). Pixel_material has for culumn that is why i have used 4 & in np.where().

Comment: I hope it is clear. Thank you.